# Refresh page after button is clicked

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a button in a current page http://localhost/checkout/purchase-confirmation/?payment_key=97de4a39e2a8c732e686d7414ff5951a

```
<form method="POST" action=''>
  <input type="submit" name="deliver_confirmation"  value=" Tôi đã nhận được đồ. Tôi đồng ý trả tiền cho Người Mua Hộ">
</form>
```

When it is clicked, it does something like sending email, update database.
And then finally, the page is refresh.

```
if (isset($_POST['deliver_confirmation']))
{
//Update payment meta of deliver_status
  $meta['deliver_status']= 'Đã giao hàng';
  edd_update_payment_meta( $payment->ID, '_edd_payment_meta', $meta);?>
//Refresh page 
  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;"<?php get_permalink( $payment->ID); ?>"'>
}                   
?>
```

The problem is that, after the page is refresh, it is redirected to

```
http://localhost/checkout/purchase-confirmation/"
```

which is a Not found page error. I dont understand where `"` character of the redirect url comes from.

Is there any better way to refresh page? Maybe adding some javascript, or blah blah...

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<?php
echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='.get_permalink( $payment->ID).'">';

?>
```

Comment: this does not work. It is redirected http://localhost/?post_type=edd_payment&p=7800

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `header()` instead:

```
header (Location: get_permalink( $payment->ID));
```

Else, if you want to use `meta refresh`, it should be:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=" . get_permalink( $payment->ID) . "'>";
```